# TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
data = np.load('fff.npy')
for line in data:
    print(line)
```

I am trying to open .npy file which is containing image features.

```
File "/home/savithri/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/savithri/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/savithri/Documents/MSRIT_MTECH_2018/MTECH_PROJECT_MAIN/data/Flicker30k_Dataset/rr.py", line 3, in <module>
    for i,line in data:

TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

Comment: Does `data` really contain data? What is the value of `data.ndim`?

Comment: The sample code has `for line in data:`, the error `for i,line in data:`.  which is it?  Before trying this, print `data.shape` and `data.dtype` to get a better idea of what `data` is like.

Comment: @PaulRooney, you can iterate on an array - it steps through the first dimension.  `nditer` is not needed for simple iteration.  Of course it's better to not iterate at all.

Comment: thank you all for your suggestions